# How to programmatically maintain aspect ratio of object in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I programmatically add a `Border` with a certain width and height to a grid. However, I want to get either one of the following:

1. Make the border keep aspect ratio and fill make it as big as possible inside the grid
2. Make the border scale whenever the grid scales down or up (so not particularily the biggest possible, more like a percentage of the grid)

At the moment this is the situation when I resize my window:

```
Color borderColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(BorderColor);
Color backgroundColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(BackgroundColor);

Border border = new Border();
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(BorderSize);
border.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(TopLeftCornerRadius, TopRightCornerRadius, BottomRightCornerRadius, BottomLeftCornerRadius);
border.BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(BorderColor));
border.Background = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(BackgroundColor));

border.Width = Width;
border.Height = Height;

border.Margin = new Thickness(10);

previewgrid.Children.Add(border);
```

The normal situation:

[image]

The scaled situation:

[image]

So I would like it to resize properly and stay inside the white rectangle. By the way, the white grid has a margin as you can see ;-)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to separate your grid to 3 columns: first and last "Auto" and middle is "*". In the middle will be rectangle and in the sides - borders.

Comment: Or maybe ViewBox can help you reach the goal

Comment: @lerthe61 looked at that indeed but couldn't figure out how exactly

Comment: Is `previewcanvas` a Canvas?

Comment: @IIVic no it's a grid, sorry forgot to change that ;-) but if it's possible with a canvas or any other sort of element, that would be good too! As long as I can draw objects in it ;-)

Comment: @Derp You can try something like that:

<!-- language: c# -->
    var viewBox = new Viewbox();
    viewBox.Child = border;
    previewgrid.Children.Add(viewBox);

Comment: Thank you @lerthe61! Your suggestion made it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As lerthe61 suggested, just use a [Viewbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.viewbox(v=vs.110).aspx) with its `Stretch` property set to `Uniform`:

```
Color borderColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(BorderColor);
Color backgroundColor = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(BackgroundColor);

Border border = new Border();
border.BorderThickness = new Thickness(BorderSize);
border.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(TopLeftCornerRadius, TopRightCornerRadius, BottomRightCornerRadius, BottomLeftCornerRadius);
border.BorderBrush = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(BorderColor));
border.Background = (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(BackgroundColor));

border.Width = Width;
border.Height = Height;

border.Margin = new Thickness(10);

Viewbox viewBox = new Viewbox();
viewBox.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
viewBox.Child = border;

previewgrid.Children.Add(viewBox);
```

Please, note that this solution does not work if `previewgrid` is a `Canvas`.
I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way:

```
 <Grid Margin="50">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border CornerRadius="50,0,0,50"
            Background="Green" />
    <Border CornerRadius="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Background="Green" />
    <Border CornerRadius="0,50,50,0"
            Grid.Column="2"
            Background="Green" />

</Grid>
```

By C#:

```
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(50) });
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(50) });

        Border b1 = new Border
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
            CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(100, 0, 0, 100)
        };

        Grid.SetColumn(b1, 0);

        Border b2 = new Border
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
        };
        Grid.SetColumn(b2, 1);
        Border b3 = new Border
        {
            Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
            CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(0, 100, 100, 0),
        };
        Grid.SetColumn(b3, 2);

        myGrid.Children.Add(b1);
        myGrid.Children.Add(b2);
        myGrid.Children.Add(b3);
```

Normal:

[image]
Resized:

[image]

Is it good enough for you?

Comment: 1. It must be done in C#, not XAML (unfortunately) and 2. it doesn't maintain aspect ratio, so unfortunately not good enough :(

Comment: @Derp Why doesn't XAML suffice?

Comment: Because it is a deserialized object from an XML file and the values can change so that wouldn't be possible with XAML (as far as I know)

Comment: You could take these values and transfer them to C# :)
The code is similar to yours, you just need to separate your grid to 3 columns and instead of 1 border use 3.
But idea is clear. Isn't it?

Comment: If you could update your answer with help that would be awesome ;) as long as you assume that the values may differ. I'm having a program that generates labels from an xml file and all labels have different dimensions, FYI

Comment: @Derp The values (like Width, Background, and CornerRadius) can just be bindings. Then your DataContext can update them on the fly.